# check if the data already exists in the sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting objectId of a row from parse. The same objectId I have saved in the sqlite databse for that corresponding object whille sending it to parse.

```
String objectId = archiveNotes.getObjectId();
```

And, then I am looking if the row with the same objectId exists in the database :

```
tasks_Database_Operations tasksDatabaseOperations = new tasks_Database_Operations(getApplicationContext());

                SQLiteDatabase database = tasksDatabaseOperations.getReadableDatabase();
                Log.d("HirakDebug", "Got readable database");
                String tablename = tasks_Database_Operations.ASSIS_NOTES_TABLE_NAME;
                String where = tasks_Database_Operations.ASSIS_NOTES_PARSE_OBJECT_ID + "=?";
                String[] whereArgs = new String[]{objectId};
                Cursor cursor = database.query(tablename, null, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    Log.d("HirakDebug", "SQHelper PArse sync data exist");

                } else {
                    Log.d("HirakDebug", "SQHelper PArse sync data doesnt exist");
                    tasksDatabaseOperations.putFromParse(objectId, archived, color, date, locked, note, title);
                    Log.d("HirakDebug", "Got from parse " + objectId + " " + archived + " " +
                            color + " " + date + " " + locked + " " + note + " " + title);
                }
```

But, I am not seeing either of the Logs from if...else statemenet in my logcat. That means none of them are executed. Neither I am getting any error.

Can anyone please findout where i am doing a mistake?

Comment: are you sure you are running your app in debug? Before checking `cursor.moveToFirst()` you should also check if cursor is not `null`.

Comment: @deadfish `SQLiteDatabase.query()` never returns `null`.

Comment: if you are not going to if-else part - it means something might be wrong in your `query()` method. I do not know, maybe you have there something like empty return..

Comment: Try stepping through with a debugger, maybe you're swallowing an exception or something.

Answer (score 0):

First, please could you write the SQL sentence you are trying to execute?

Second, Do you realy want to pass NULL on the second paramter for the columns?

Third, Have you tried replacing the database.query for the db.rawQuery and see what happens?, if so please tell me.

Thanks